Show that $S(A, B) = S(B) − S(A)$ iff $\rho_i^A$ have a common eigenbasis and $\rho_i^B$ have orthogonal support

This exercise is from Quantum Computation and Quantum Information. Suppose the equality holds, and that $|ABR\rangle=\sum_i\sqrt{\lambda_i}|i\rangle_{AB}|i\rangle_{R}$ (with $\lambda_i>0$) is a purification of $\rho^{AB}$.
Then we have
\begin{align*}
\rho^{ABR}&=\sum_{ij}\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}|i\rangle\langle j|\otimes |i\rangle\langle j|,\\
\rho^{AR}&=\sum_{ij}\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}\operatorname{tr}_B(|i\rangle\langle j|)\otimes |i\rangle\langle j|,\\
\rho^R&=\sum_i\lambda_i|i\rangle \langle i|.
\end{align*}
The identity $S(A,B)=S(B)-S(A)$ is equivalent to $\rho^{AR}=\rho^A\otimes \rho^R$, thus
\begin{align}
\sum_{ij}\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}\operatorname{tr}_B(|i\rangle\langle j|)\otimes |i\rangle\langle j|=\sum_{ij}\lambda_i\lambda_j \rho_i^A\otimes|j\rangle\langle j|.
\end{align}
It follows that $\operatorname{tr}_B(|i\rangle \langle j|)=0$ for $i\neq j$.
For any fixed $j$, we have $\lambda_j(\sum_i\lambda_i\rho_i^A-\rho_j^A)=0$, so $\rho_j^A=\sum_i \lambda_i\rho_i^A$ is constant, which is stronger than the statement $\{\rho_j^A\}$ have a common basis in the exercise. Is this an error? The statement for $\{\rho_i^B\}$ also seems false as in the comments of this post Prove the equality conditions in the triangle inequality $S(A,B)\ge |S(A)-S(B)|$ for the von Neumann entropy . From the above there shouldn't be any restrictions on $\{\rho_i^B\}$.

what do you mean with "the equality is equivalent to $\rho^{AR}=\rho^A\otimes\rho^R$? What equality? For a product state you have $S(A,R)=S(A)+S(R)$, not $S(A,R)=S(R)-S(A)$.

@glS Please check the proof of this theorem in QCQI. $S(A)+S(R)\geq S(A,R),S(A,R)=S(B),S(R)= S(A,B)$.

sure... but I don't really see how that relates with what I asked

@glS The equality is $S(A,B)=S(B)-S(A)$ which is equivalent to $S(A,R)=S(A)+S(R)$

yes ok now it's clearer. Where did you get the identity $\lambda_j(\sum_i\rho_i^A-\rho_j^A)=0$ though?

@glS That is simple. If the second register is fixed to be $|j><j|$, the first register of both side should be equal.

indeed, but I still don't see where you get that identity. From the RHS, projecting the second space on $|j\rangle$, you get $\lambda_j\sum_i \lambda_i\rho^A_i$. From the LHS you get $\lambda_j \rho^A_j$. Your identity seems to be missing a $\lambda_i$ factor in the sum (though I agree you reach the same conclusion from that)

@glS You are right. I missed $\lambda_i$.
